# ''Téléchargement'' to ''Download''

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I am with Ubuntu 18.04. I changed Ubuntu to be in English instead of French, but there's still some French things. For instance, all the Download are heading to ''Téléchargements'' instead of ''Downlaod''. How can I change that?

Comment: What are the contents of your `~/.config/user-dirs.locale` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default common folder names should automatically change when you change system language.
Two utilities should be run at startup for that (`xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update` and `xdg-user-dirs-update`).

I recommend you to manually **set folder names** and **edit the files**
- `/home/$USER/.config/user-dirs.dirs` : path and folder names
- `/home/$USER/.config/user-dirs.locale` : desktop language

You may rename your folders and edit the `user-dirs.dirs` file

```
mv /home/$USER/Téléchargements /home/$USER/Downloads
sed  's/Téléchargements/Downloads/g' /home/$USER/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

You may also use the [`xdg-user-dirs-update`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xdg-utils) program.

**More information** about Cross-desktop interoperability standards
XDG user directories : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_user_directories (i love Arch docs)
xdg-user-dirs : https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you go to the aplication called " language support". It is in the preferences tab of the menu.
Maybe there's some files that arent downloaded yet, so you see some things in French instead of English.
If that is the case, the aplication should pop up a message saying that the language support is incomplete, and requesting download the files.